# Code checks one drive for three different drive letters

Tags: vbscript

So I have created a code that reads the following text file:

```
Diskspace   C:
Diskspace   D:
Diskspace   E:

Memory
CPU
```

And check usage for each type of "hardware" listed.

I only have a disk C: on my computer, so how can I put an error message for any disk that doesn't work?

What happens in my script now is since I have "On Error Resume Next", my code checks whatever disk it can analyze, and inputs that answer (aka disk C:) for each disk. For example, in my wscript.echo box, it says

```
Disk C: is 93.4% free.  
Disk D: is 93.4% free.  
Disk E: is 93.4% free.
```

I know that this is wrong.

```
On Error Resume Next 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("M:\vbscripts\ServerHealthCheck_Control.txt")


message = ""

Do While objReadFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    strLine = objReadFile.ReadLine

    If Left(strLine, 1) = "D" then
        letter = Mid(strLine, 11, 2)
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set drive = fso.GetDrive(letter)
        totalSpace = drive.TotalSize / 1024
        freeSpace = drive.AvailableSpace / 1024
        percentFree = freeSpace / totalSpace

        number = FormatNumber(percentFree*100, 2)
        'WARNING_MESSAGE = Mid(strLine, 14, 2)
        'ERROR_MESSAGE = Mid(strLine, 17, 2)

        message = message & "Drive " & letter & " is " & number & "% free." & vbCrlf

    Elseif Left(strLine, 1) = "M" then
        Const CONVERT = 1048576 ' This is total bytes in 1 MB.
        Const strComputer = "."
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
        Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
        For Each objOperatingSystem in colSettings
            intFreeMem = objOperatingSystem.FreePhysicalMemory / CONVERT
            intTotalMem = objOperatingSystem.TotalVisibleMemorySize / CONVERT
            Memory = intFreeMem / intTotalMem * 100

            message = message & "Memory is " & FormatNumber(Memory,2) & "% free." & vbCrlf
        Next

    Elseif Left(strLine, 1) = "C" then
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\localhost\root\CIMV2") 
        Set CPUInfo = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor",,48) 
        For Each Item in CPUInfo 
            If Item.Name = "_Total" Then
                    message = message & "Total CPU usage is " & Item.PercentProcessorTime & "%."
            End If
        Next
    End If

Loop

Wscript.Echo message
```

EDIT: I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
If fso.GetDrive(letter) = error then
    message = message & "The drive " & letter & " cannot be read."
Elseif fso.GetDrive(letter) <> error then
    totalSpace = drive.TotalSize / 1024
    freeSpace = drive.AvailableSpace / 1024
    percentFree = freeSpace / totalSpace

    number = FormatNumber(percentFree*100, 2)
    message = message & "Drive " & letter & " is " & number & "% free." & vbCrlf
End If
```

It displays that E: is an error, but disk D still copies disk C.

Comment: after you have done a loop reset all your variables

Comment: Test if this line raises an error `Set drive = fso.GetDrive(letter)` using `If err.number <> 0 then : msgbox "no exist": err.clear : End If` (`:` allows two commands on one line)

Comment: I have tried putting "drive = nothing" under my first "End If" but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Your logic isn't very good. In my snippit above you put your logic in an `else` clause so you only do your processing if it exists. And replace the `msgbox` with code that says *Not available*.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help on WMI by using the command line utility `wmic /?` and `wmic logicaldisk get /?`

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,freespace
```

outputs the freespace on ALL drives. In VBScript the above becomes

```
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk")
For Each objdisk in colSettings
    wscript.echo objdisk.caption & " " & objdisk.freespace
Next
```

You can use a where clause in both VBScript or WMIC.

```
wmic logicaldisk where (caption="C:" or caption="D:" or caption="E:") get caption,freespace
```

Comment: I only need to check specified disks in my script. Sometimes the disks exist, sometimes they do not

Answer (score 0):

Replace the EVIL global OERN with a strictly local one (a call of a Sub/Function containing the risky operation(s)). As in:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function RiskyGetDrive(sDL)
' maybe lots of lines here, immediate exit on first error
  Set RiskyGetDrive = goFS.GetDrive(sDL) ' could be unavailable
  Dim dummy : dummy = RiskyGetDrive.TotalSize ' could be not ready
End Function

Dim sDL, oDrv, aErr
For Each sDL in Split("C D E Q")
  ' error hiding for just one risky operation and copy of (possible) error data
  On Error Resume Next
    Set oDrv = RiskyGetDrive(sDL)
    aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If aErr(0) Then
     WScript.Echo sDL, "Diag:", aErr(0), aErr(1)
  Else
     'not needed, if "not ready" is provoked in function
     'If Not oDrv.IsReady Then
     '   WScript.Echo sDL, "Diag:", "not ready"
     'Else
     '   WScript.Echo sDL, "Info:", oDrv.TotalSize / 1024
     'End If
     WScript.Echo sDL, "Info:", oDrv.TotalSize / 1024
  End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 41173138.vbs
C Info: 41929616
D Diag: 71 Disk not ready
E Info: 227784528
Q Diag: 68 Device unavailable
```